# Run command line programs

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

I need help to writing a Python application that needs to run other command line afflictions. For example, when I push "BLABLA" button the Python application call function that run in command line `c:\test> BLA.exe blabla`, the function return same string so I need to store it in a variable.

So, I don't know how to run command line programs from within Python and get the strings back form that program.

Comment: I saw the post and don't understand it ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully. I removed the duplicate flag. But actually it's answered on [a different stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)...

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output of the command, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/3419103) might help:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

So in your case the one line might look like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['BLA.exe', 'blabla'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: It work only one time , if I run it again with 'blabla2 ' in same program it make some wrong staf ( if i run it directly via command line it work fine :BLA.exe blabla , enter, BLA.exe blabla2 ,enter...  ) Any ideas ?

Comment: @MAXK: Hm, make sure your program does not change the working directory. But for a more detailed error analysis you might describe the "wrong staff" and post your python code.